# C# button style minesweeper

Tags: c#, winforms, button, minesweeper

I am currently doing on classic minesweeper in c#. I want to support middle click like in basic minesweeper, which count mines around and if this number is equal to count of fields marked as mine, reveal rest of the field which are not marked as mine.

Since this I do not want button which is already revealed to be disabled, because it is still possible to click on this button to support that middle click functionality.

But I do want to set some property which almost looks like button is disabled, something like when you click on a button and hold.

Any ideas ? 
TY Peter

Comment: win forms, forget about this info

Comment: With WinForms the best way is to (find an existing game board or) create a custom control and handle the drawing and input manually. Then you have full control over the display (and avoid creating hundreds or thousands of native buttons/windows!).

Comment: I think my implementations works fine. I implements class MineButton: Button which in constructor take 4 arguments, positions and position in array, then dynamically put them on form and give all of them one same event handler on mousedown. Then I can easily distinguish in which button was clicked, because of that position  property.

Comment: If it works fine then don't worry about it .. (and then I'm confused at purpose of the question.) I still recommend using custom rendering, even if only per-button.

Comment: If onclick I set Enabled on False I cannot click on it anymore to support that midle button functionality or even set different colors to text which represents how many mines are around button. I want some property or style, do not really know how to say it, so that button if button is clicked it changes its looking to somthing like when you click on button and hold. Something whch sends button litle back, do not really know how to say it in English, best explanation in my opinion is when you click on button and hold.

Comment: Flat style was what I was looking for :)